# webkit transition not seeming to work in some box-shadow rules

Tags: css-transitions, css

I want an expandable tree in a table cell. I got that to work. While playing around with it, I tried to add a transitioned box shadow. That works only at the root level. [(JsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/RussAbbott/6xQpZ/44/).

The problem may have something to do with transitions not working on display [(link)](http://goo.gl/YByD8). But does a display change foul up all transitions, or am I missing something? (I only put in a webkit transition.)

Thanks.

Comment: afaik box-shadow-transitions are not officially supported. And there *cannot* be a sensible transition between `display` states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This might be a possible workaround, since the transition effect isn't working.

Have you tried using keyframe animations? I did some changes in the code. Here's a [demo (jsFiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/KYHBA/1/)

I changed:

```
/* This transition seems to have no effect. */
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
```

to:

```
/* This transition seems to have no effect. */
    -webkit-animation: shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
}  

@-webkit-keyframes shadow {
    0%   { box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000; }    
    100% { box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px #000; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm really interested in why the transition didn't work.